# how many complex solutions does this equation have?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Can someone explain me how to analyse and see the total number of complex solutions for this equation:

[image]

Comment: Use polar coordinates:  $r^{n-1} e^{(n-1)\theta i} = re^{i(-\theta +\frac \pi 4) + 2k\pi i}$.

Comment: Could you give me, if you have time, a more detailed explanation? I'm just a passionate about math and I tried to use Euler Formula but it didn't work for me

Comment: Well we have $|i\overline z| = |z| = |z|^{n-1}$ so (if $|z|\ne 0$) $|z|=1$ and $z= e^{i\theta}$ for some angle $\theta$.  $z^{n-1}=e^{i(n-1)\theta}$.  Meanwhile $i = e^{i\frac \pi 4}$ and $\overline z = e^{-i\theta}$.  So we have $e^{i(n-1)\theta}=e^{i(-\theta+\frac \pi 4)}$.  So $(n-1)\theta = -\theta+\frac \pi 4 + 2k\pi$.  Solve for $\theta$...

Comment: Yeah, WA Don's approach is almost certainly the intended approach.  $\overline z\cdot z = |z|^2$ so $z^n = i|z|^2$.  And as $|z^n| = |z|^n$ and $|iM|=|M|$ we have $|z|^n = |z|^2$ so (assuming $z\ne  0)$, that $|z| = 1|$ so we have $z^n =i$ which... well, you should know there are $n$ solutions to that.

Comment: THank you both. But also z can be 0 => n+1 solutions, right?

Comment: Often it is assumed $z\ne 0$.  So double check that it never stated that.  If so, yes, there are $n$ solutions for $z^n =i$ and one for $z=0$ an so there are $n+1$ solutions.

Comment: @fleablood thank you. it don't say in the problem that z != 0. so, I will accept n+1 solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107498/discussion-between-akhtubir-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach.

Clearly $ z = 0$ is one solution.  Otherwise, multiply by $ z $ to obtain

$$ z^n = i | z |^2 $$

Plainly, unless $n=2$ we must have $|z| = 1 $, so we have

$$ z^n= i $$

And therefore $z$ is either $0$ or one of the $n$ roots of $i$.

If $n=2$, then, using real and imaginary parts,

$$ x+iy = i(x-iy) $$

So every multiple of $1 + i$ is a solution.

Comment: Why you deleted your demonstration? It might help me to understand better

Comment: Sorry - just (I hope) improved it!

Comment: n roots of i => that means we have n solutions for the initially given equation? Or n+1 because z = 0 is one solution?

Comment: $z^n = i$ has $n$ solutions.  If we allow $z = 0$ as a solution there is one more.  So there are $n + 1$ solutions. (If we allow $z =0$).

Comment: @WADon can you explain this: Plainly, unless n=2 we must have |z|=1, so we have

zn=i ?

Comment: I don't understand why $|z|^2$ = 1

Comment: To see $|z| = 1$ take the modulus of both sides:  $|z|^n=|z^n| = |i| |z|^2 =|z|^2$.  This can only hold (for $ n > 2$) if $z=0$ or $|z| = 1$.

Comment: great. all clear now